# Getting the count of 2 fields in a collection using Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

> I have a collection called ActivityCollection. There are many fields
>   in it but I want to get only two fields name Acitivity and
>   Tags of all activities. I also want to calculate the total
>   number of counts of each Activity and Tag. For more clear
>   understanding see this image given below

.[Click this link to view the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdJAO.png)

Comment: let us know what you have tried.

Comment: The only "clear understanding" we presently have is that no code in the question is a likely indication that you have not tried anything and makes it appear that you are looking for someone to do your work for you. A picture of a graph does not describe your present data or what part of the task needs explaining. And that is the purpose here to "explain" and "teach". Questions in this form look more like workorders for a job board. You would do well to amend this and show us the work you have that you need help with.

Comment: Can you provide what have you done and also the db structure

Answer (score 0):

Assuming following data model in your ActivityCollection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c4894e465dc895af90d2c"),
    "activity" : "Phone Call",
    "tag" : "Addiction"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c48a2e465dc895af90d2d"),
    "activity" : "Phone Call",
    "tag" : "Family Issue"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c48aee465dc895af90d2e"),
    "activity" : "Email",
    "tag" : "Family Issue"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c48b9e465dc895af90d2f"),
    "activity" : "Email",
    "tag" : "Depression"
}
```

**Following aggregate jobs will return the data required for your dashboard:**

For count based on activity:

```
db.ActivityCollection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$activity", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

For count based on tag:

```
 db.ActivityCollection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$tag", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

**The following will result respectively**:

For activity based:

```
{ "_id" : "Email", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Phone Call", "count" : 2 }
```

For tag based:

```
{ "_id" : "Depression", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Family Issue", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Addiction", "count" : 1 }
```